# How to use dijit requires in parsed dojo ContentPane

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, js-amd

I am trying to do a simple task. This task is to load a HTML containg `dijit.Form` into a `ContentPane`. I don't know which dijits I will need before I load this HTML, but the loaded HTML will contain applicable `require`'s to load them.

So in order to be able to execute the script from loaded HTML I use `dojox.layout.ContentPane`. However when I set `parseOnLoad` to `true`, the parsing takes place **before** the script execution, so the dijits aren't available when first loading the content. Also when I try to use `onDownloadEnd` callback, when this callback is run, the dijits from `require`'s are still not loaded.

Only thing I can think of myself is using `setTimeout` to defer parsing to a time when these scripts will be executed. I don't like this solution however as it may fail from time to time and it would make the application less responsible.

So how should I perform the parsing so that it happens right after the `require` statement from loaded HTML is run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions - both with `dijit/layout/ContentPane`:

1. Use Dojo 1.8.0, as the parser supports [auto require](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/parser#auto-require), it will load dependencies itself as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/vr4h4/
2. Put the list of dependencies somewhere into your form template, e.g. in `data-config` attribute of your `dijit/form/Form`:

   ```
   <form 
       data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" 
       data-config='"deps":["dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Button"]'>

       <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" data-dojo-props="placeholder:'TextBox'">
       <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Button</button>

   </form>
   ```

   Set `parseOnLoad:false` for the `dijit/layout/ContentPane`, load the template, get the list of dependencies, `require` them and then in the factory function `parser.parse()` `containerNode` of your `ContentPane` (see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/QA4gH/):

   ```
   require([
       "dojo/ready",
       "dojo/dom",
       "dojo/query",
       "dojo/on",
       "dojo/parser",
       "dojo/json",
       "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
       "dojo/domReady!"
   ], function(ready, dom, query, on, parser, JSON) {

       var template, dijits;

       ready(function() {
           template = dom.byId("template").textContent;
           on.once(dom.byId("loadFormButton"), "click", loadForm);
           contentPane1.set("parseOnLoad", false);
           contentPane1.on("load", parseForm);
       });

       function loadForm() {
           contentPane1.set("content", template);  
       }

       function parseForm() {
           // a node to parse
           var node = contentPane1.containerNode;
           // obtain a list of dependencies
           var config = JSON.parse("{" + query("form", node)[0].dataset.config + "}");

           // require (AMD load) dependencies
           require(config.deps, function() {
               // parse ContentPane content when dependencies are resolved
               dijits = parser.parse(node); 
               console.log(dijits); // an array of instantiated dijits
           });
       }      
   });
   ​
   ```

**EDIT**: I just got this idea that writing an auto require (for Dojo <1.8) is just about adding a short `getDependencies()` method, so you don't need to list dependencies as I mentioned in the second option above:

```
function getDependencies(/*DOMNode*/ containerNode) {
    var deps = [];
    query("[data-dojo-type]", containerNode).forEach(function(node) {
        var dep = node.dataset.dojoType.split(".").join("/");
        if(!~array.indexOf(deps, dep)) {
            deps.push(dep);
        };            
    });
    return deps;
}
```

See it working at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/hnjWt/

Comment: +1 for rewriting OP's application logic - and for ditching dojox.layout.ContentPane.executeScripts  :)

Answer (score 1):

Only option you have is to set dojoConfig.async = false or set in the require statements in your code.

The modules are not loaded for this reason; require() does not block - and whilst it is still downloading modules - the parser runs.

See http://jsfiddle.net/zA9cJ/1/ for running sample of this

```
require(["dojox/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(pane) {

    var p = new pane({ parseOnLoad: true, executeScripts: true }, 'container');
    var content = '<script type="text/javascript">'+
        'require('+
        //////////////////////////
        '{async:false},'+ ////////
        //////////////////////////
        '["dijit/form/Button"]);'+
        '<'+'/script>'+
        '<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Button</div>';
    p.set("content", content);
});​
```